# Auto Populate and Export Cloud Firestore Database {Collection} to BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to connect the firestore collection in auto populate method to BigQuery by following github https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/firestore-bigquery-export. The successfull export shows the collection with comma separated(example: Data{id,geolocation,market,customer_name,customer_id,..} which causing difficult to visualize.

I also tried export using cloud storage bucket but its not auto update in BigQuery, whenever there is changes in particular collection from firestore.

Need help on this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sync data between Firestore and BigQuery by 2 ways:

1. Creating and triggering a **Cloud Function** whenever there is a change in a Firestore collection and streaming those changes into BigQuery table.
2. Using the [**"Export Collections to BigQuery" Firebase Extension**](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-bigquery-export).

Also please have a look into the following [tutorial](https://www.the-swamp.info/blog/exporting-data-firebase-firestore-bigquery/)